# Trying to run selenium grid batchfile from java

Tags: java, selenium, batch-processing

I'm trying to Selenium Grid server batch file from my java code. But I'm not able to do it.

I'm getting error as unable to find jar file. But when i double click it and run from folder, its working. But I'm trying to run this batch file from TestNG Class (inside the code).

Please help me get started. Thanks much for the help.

#### Batch file

```
java -jar ";Selenium APIs\selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar;" -role hub -port 4444
pause
```

#### Java Code

```
File ff = new File(".");
try {

    String pt = ff.getCanonicalPath()+"\\Selenium APIs\\Start Selenium Server.bat"; 
    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", pt};
    Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);           
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
```

When i run this, CMD is opening but the commands in the batch file is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> ;Selenium APIs\selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar;

Try using an absolute path, and removing the path seperators:

```
java -jar "C:\Selenium\Selenium APIs\selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar" -role hub -port 4444
pause
```

Comment: no im still facing the same issue. moreover i cant use the absolute path as this batch file can be executed in other systems too. :(

Comment: @Shankar What was the solution?